# Advanced Array.prototype.filter with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an Javascript object like so...

```
var strategies = [{
    "strategy": {
        "category": "war"
    }
}, {
    "strategy": {
        "category": "farming"
    }
}]
```

I then have an array that indicates which results I'd like back. It can be any of the following: `[]` OR `["war"]` `["farming"]` OR `["war", "farming"]`.

If we have the `[]`, I want to return no results. But if `["war", "farming"]` I want to return both of the results above.

How do I accomplish this with [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/filter)? I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes), but couldn't reason through it.

```
strategies.filter((strategy) => 
  ????
)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: so, strategy is the object.  You need to return true if it matches within the function, or false if not.  It sounds like you are filtering a set on an array

Comment: And you can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to find out if an array contains a given value.

Comment: Good point Gents. If I get a value above -1 in indexOf I could return true

Answer (score 4):

You can just check the value with [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
var categories = ['war', 'farming'];

var filtered = strategies.filter((obj) => {
  return categories.indexOf(obj.strategy.category) > -1;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I need. Will accept when possible.

Comment: @thedanotto sweet!

Answer (score 1):

Your object, strategy was a wrapped object, so my first line was setting it to its inner strategy and then filter as needed.

```
var strategies = [{
    "strategy": {
        "category": "war"
    }
}, {
    "strategy": {
        "category": "farming"
    }
}]
var b = ["war", "farming"];
strategies.filter(function(strategy){
   strategy = strategy.strategy;
   for(var i in b){
     if (b[i] == strategy["category"]) {
        return true;
      }
  }
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Tests the input array to see if it's empty as per your requirements:

```
function filterObj(arr) {
  return !arr.length ?  arr :
  strategies.filter((el) => arr.indexOf(el.strategy.category) > -1);
}

filterObj(['war', 'farming'])
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Lu4upsys/)